# Forwarding website to IP address on router, "DNS resolution" / what else would it be called?

Tags: router, dns

I use the "DNS routing" feature of my BT 2Wire router to forward all local traffic for http://testserver.example to a specific IP address ie 192.168.1.2.

I want to get a new router, but want to make sure it has these capabilities. Can anyone help me work out what language to look for in the tech specs to check if a router has these capabilities?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a DNS server. Unfortunately I don't have a list of home routers with this functionality. If you are just doing this for a few computers that are always on the network your could always just edit the hosts file.

You could also setup your own DNS server on an old PC or even the web server if your network is low traffic.

Comment: I don't really want to set up the whole DNS server myself (I'm happy using openDNS or BT's standard DNS and don't want the faff of having to manage this myself), I just want to override certain domains, exactly like you can with the hosts file but for everyone on the local network at the same time. It's just not practical to do this manually for everyone in hosts. It's "DNS resolution" on the 2Wire router, but I don't know about anywhere else. Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Usually forwarding requests from public ip into a certain server inside your network for the whole ports in one shot is called on home routers "DMZ"

If you want to forward a domain, (while the ip address is dynamic) its called dynamic dns

Comment: I don't think DMZ is what I want, because I only want this to happen with local traffic, plus for each domain I want to specify the specific IP address of the computer that should handle the traffic. This IP will be static though: it'll always be 192.168.1.100 or 192.168.1.101.